# Find the pdf of Y if Y = |X|

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a random variable with pdf

$f_X(x) = \frac13$ if $-1<x<2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Let $Y=|X|$, find the pdf of $Y$.

My thought process follows: Y is nonzero from $0<y<2$. Since the interval from 0 to 1 includes $-1<x<1$, using integration I find that the pdf of Y is

$f_Y(y) = \frac23$ if $0<y<1$ and $\frac13$ if $1<y<2$, 0 otherwise.

Is my rationale correct? I feel like my explanation makes intuitive sense but is not elegant.

Comment: It is correct. In order to formalize you could determine the CDF of $|X|$ and then differentiate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is okay.

---

Reality Check: is $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \tfrac 23\mathrm d y+\int_1^2 \tfrac 13\mathrm d y=1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.